# Identify xpath for tag with negative number

Tags: xpath, qtp

Need help in identifying xpath for the below tag

```
<span tabIndex='-1' class=...../>
```

I want all the elements that have `"tabindex"` attribute with a value "-1".

When i write `//span[@tabindex]` and put it in a loop it retrieves all the elements with tabindex attribute but its not the same when I write `//span[@tabindex = '-1']`. It returns 0 elements even though there are 5 different elements are available with same html tag.

I am not sure if this is the correct way to write xpath for negative numbers. Please correct me and requesting help

Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
Set odesc=Description.Create()
    odesc("micclass").value="WebElement" 
    odesc("xpath").value="//span[@tabIndex]" 

set test = Browser("asdfasdf").Page("asdfasdf").ChildObjects(odesc)
k=0
msgbox test.count
    For i = 1 To test.count-1
        val=test(i).GetROProperty("innertext")
        MsgBox val
        k=k+1
    Next
```

Now when `odesc("xpath").value="//span[@tabIndex]"` i get 22 elements and i wanted to filter it out with attribute value having -1

HTML Code:

```
<span tabIndex="-1" class=...../>
```

When i update the same xpath `"//span[@tabIndex='-1']"` **it gives back 0 elements which is incorrect as there are 5 elements with that tag**

Comment: Please provide more information. `//span[@tabindex = '-1']` works for me.

Comment: @Sriram It should work. `//span[@tabindex = '-1']` should select all such elements. Please show us your complete Input and code.

Answer (score 0):

XML is case sensitive. `I` and `i` are different:

```
 tabindex
@tabIndex
    ^
```

Comment: My Bad :(. It is tabIndex. Copy paste error from my end. I have updated the question